# Why .then() which is in useEffect is not updating my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state

targetMovie is null when it comes to rednering. I couldn't find any solutions. First time having unsolvable problem. Please help!

```
async function getMovie(id) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(apiEndPoint + "/" + id);
    const movies = await res.data;
    return movies;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

const MovieEdit = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [targetMovie, setTargetMovie] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovie(id)
      .then((mov) => {
        setTargetMovie(mov);
        console.log(mov);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  console.log(targetMovie);
  if (targetMovie) return <AddMovie movie={targetMovie} />;
  return <Navigate to="/not-found" />;
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Can you please [edit] your question to describe what you expect to see vs what you actually see. Does your logging show what you expect?

Comment: Feels clear to me. OP thinks `<AddMovie>` is being rendered with a null `targetMovie`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I don't see how that one applies here

Comment: Ah, you're using `<Navigate>` from react-router. I think you should read the docs for that component ~ https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate

Comment: Just FYI a more accurate title would be something more along the lines of "Why is my component navigating away from the page prior to fetching data?" The initial `targetMovie` state is falsey so the `Navigate` component is rendered the and navigation action is effected on the initial render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to represent 3 states:

1. You're currently waiting on getMovie to complete
2. getMovie completed successfully
3. getMovie completed and returned null/undefined

You're currently using the same condition (`!targetMovie`) to represent both 1. and 3. which is why you're running into issues.

Try this:

```
const MovieEdit = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true);
  const [targetMovie, setTargetMovie] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovie(id)
      .then((mov) => {
        setIsFetching(false);
        setTargetMovie(mov);
        console.log(mov);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err));
        setIsFetching(false);
      }
  }, []);

  if (isFetching) return null;

  if (targetMovie) return <AddMovie movie={targetMovie} />;

  return <Navigate to="/not-found" />;
};
```

Comment: Note that I'd recommend using something like react-query (https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview) to actually implement the logic of fetching stuff.

Comment: I'd suggest also adding the missing `id` variable to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook so when it updates the relevant movie data can again be fetched.

Comment: isFetching state solved it. Adding id to the dependencies of useEffect was also helpful. Thanks a lot